# jwt token in DOTNET WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt

I literally read the internet through, tried multiple approaches and so on - with no luck.

I am trying to make a pretty small WebApi project with a few controllers protected by a jwt token.

I generate the token using following code:

```
    var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("may the force"));

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims.ToArray()),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

I have setup the authentication (in Startup.cs) bits like

```
services.AddAuthentication(x => {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }
            )
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("may the force"))
                };
            });
```

Using my AuthController I can generate the Token(first code block in this question) - and the Controllers needed to be "protected" is annotated with [Authorize]

If I take the result from AuthController and paste it at https://jwt.io the signature is valid.

I am testing the controllers using postman and setting the request header Authorization to Bearer <the token>

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks alot!

UPDATE: I misused the jwt.io site initially, thus some of the comments underneath here are no longer valid.

UPDATE 2: Realized that the server tried to use cookie based authentication. Changing the annotation to [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] made the trick - but still not sure why

Comment: Damn.... 2nd thought, just noticed the "secret base64 encoded
" checkbox :(
However the real problem persists - the controllers still rejects even the the Authorization "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IkdMU0RLIiwicm9sZSI6IkNBUlJJRVIiLCJDYXJyaWVyQ29kZSI6IkdMU0RLIiwibmJmIjoxNTcyOTAyNjU5LCJleHAiOjE1NzM1MDc0NTksImlhdCI6MTU3MjkwMjY1OX0.7yZh64akTfI-C74XSt6GjvgjPur_91oLfasdfasdfVE" header added

Comment: @jps it was just a misspelling. But the concept was right. You should paste the secret key to get the right verification result.

Comment: You don't need the `Bearer` part. Just psate the hash and fill the secret key box.

Comment: @MasLoo not sure if I get it - but I tried to set a header key = Authorization, and the Value to the Token. No luck!
Does the code pasted from Startup.cs look sane?

Comment: @masLoo Sorry for being unclear here. jwt.io validates as it should. But postman is being rejected by the controllers.

Comment: Take a look at this [tutorial](https://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/). It's a part of seris about token authentication in web api. There you can find the right way to make Http requests in token authentication.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201858/discussion-between-the-eternal-newbie-and-masloo).